# Commit git-svn changes to SVN repo

Tags: git-svn

we have a central SVN repo in our company. I use git-svn on my laptop to be able to use a repo, when I'm not connected to the company network.
Now I was 3 weeks on a business trip and committed a lot to my local Git repo. There were also many commits to the SVN repo.
When I try "SVN Rebase" I have to edit conflicts in each of my Git changesets. What I would like to do is just to commit all of my local changes at once and then edit conflicts only once.

I'm fairly new to Git, so I don't know how this is done properly and if this is the best way. 
I use TortoiseGit on Windows, so up to now I didn't really care about the command line.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you go through conflict resolution in `git-svn rebase` once you are in a new tree with new commits that include your resolutions.  A future `git-svn rebase` will not encounter the same problems (unlike repeated merges, which is where `rerere` comes in handy).

If by "commit all my local changes at once" you mean you want to fold all of your commits into a single commit in git (and later SVN) then you can use `git rebase -i` to "squash" all of your commits into a single commit.  You should not include any revisions that have already been sent to SVN with `dcommit` in that `rebase -i` because you are rewriting history.  You will still have to resolve conflicts when you `git-svn rebase` just like you would if you were using only SVN and did `svn update`.

Comment: My problem is, when I try to "SVN rebase" I have 15 git commits. If I try to squash them into one SVN commit I still have to edit conflicts in every single git commit. I expected, when I squash only my latest git commit would be compared to the SVN repo.

Comment: @Simon when you say "squash them into one SVN commit" do you mean into one *git* commit prior to doing `git-svn rebase`?  If so you may get many conflicts but it will all be one revision.

Comment: All the changes are already committed to the local git repo. I assumed, when I use "SVN Rebase" with squash (at least TortoiseGit shows me a checkbox :-), I would do only one commit to the SVN repo.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what TortoiseGit is going under the hood there.  From your description it sounds like `svn rebase` + `rebase -i`/squash + `svn dcommit`.  You want the sequence `rebase -i`/squash + `svn rebase` + `svn dcommit`.  Personally I prefer to keep the multiple commits (or squash closely related changes) so users of the SVN repo can see the progression.

Comment: Okay, I did it without stash and although it was some work to review all the conflicts, it seems to be ok now. thanks for your explanations